# Sybase BCP User and Password Encrypt

Tags: ssis, sybase, bcp

Actually I'm working in a process that uses SSIS to manipulate some info and I needed to find a way to import data from a file to a Sybase ISQL Database since the Data Flow Task didn't give the performance we hoped for. I've done some test using Sybase BCP utility and it worked. The thing is that I'll like to know if there's a way to hide or encrypt the user and password used in the BCP instruction, more than anything for security reasons.

Here's an example of the instruction used:

```
/C C:\sybase\OCS-15_0\bin\bcp.exe DB..Table in C:\CSVFile.csv -c -t"|" -Sserver -Uuser -Ppassword
```

I'll appreciate your time and help.

Greetings fellow programmers :D!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the -X command-line flag to use login password encryption (i.e. the password is encrypted over the network).

If you want to hide the password from the command line, check out http://www.isug.com/Sybase_FAQ/ASE/section4.html (that's for 'isql' but some can be applied to bcp as well.

I don't think you can hide the user from the command line.

Comment: Amazing, I'll give it a try. Thanks a lot for your help! :D